# Paper size in paper setup of Excel 2010 grayed out

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, microsoft-excel-2010, windows-server-2008-r2, network-printer

i have a workstation with a network printer installed that i use to RDP to another machine.  while the printer works fine on the host, within the RDP session the redirected printer seems to gray out the paper size in Excel 2010, Word and Outlook are not affected.  Host is win7 the remote machine is W2k8.  i have admin rights on the host but not the remote machine.  other users are not affected.  i have installed the latest drivers for the printers.

Comment: Is the 2008 RDP Server using [Easy Print](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/09/28/using-remote-desktop-easy-print-in-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx)?

Comment: sorry for the delay, yes it is.